# Eclipse RCP : How to register a Jface action with Workbench Site key binding service?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, key-bindings

I am new to the Java Programming. And I don't have knowledge with replacing deprecated existing code.

Currently, in the code, Undo & Redo Jface actions are registered to workbench site key binding service as shown below,

```
/** Performs Undo Action */
        String undoID = ActionFactory.UNDO.getId();
        IAction undoAction = getActionRegistry().getAction(undoID);
        getEditorSite().getActionBars().setGlobalActionHandler(undoID,
                undoAction);
        getSite().getKeyBindingService().registerAction(undoAction);

        /** Performs Redo Action */
        String redoID = ActionFactory.REDO.getId();
        IAction redoAction = getActionRegistry().getAction(redoID);
        getEditorSite().getActionBars().setGlobalActionHandler(redoID,
                redoAction);
        getSite().getKeyBindingService().registerAction(redoAction);
```

'

Now we know that key binding service is depreciated. So how can we replace the above code with new  binding services? What are these new services? How i can know them?

Simply put, how to register a Jface action with current workbench site key binding service?

Please share any information, very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Since that is a handler for a global action I don't think you need to register the key binding at all as the global action definition should have done that.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your reply. You mean to say "getEditorSite().getActionBars().setGlobalActionHandler(redoID,
                redoAction);" is enough. This Global Action Handler will register key binding.

Comment: Yes. This code is just defining the action for Undo / Redo in this particular editor. Eclipse has already set up the standard key bindings for this, you should not need to do that.